# What is wrong with my data binding on a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, wpf-controls

I have a ComboBox marked up as:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TitleCombo"
            Width="100" 
            Height="20"
            DisplayMemberPath="TITLE_NAME"     
            SelectedValuePath="TITLE_CODEID"     
            DataContext="{Binding}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Titles}" />
```

It is the sole control on `NoticeWindow.xaml`, which has the following code-behind:

```
public partial class NoticeWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Xt900Context _dbContext = new Xt900Context();
    public NoticeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var tits = _dbContext.TITLEs.ToList();
        Titles = new ObservableCollection<TITLE>(tits);
        DataContext = this;
        TitleCombo.ItemsSource = Titles;
    }
    ObservableCollection<TITLE> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Without the `TitleCombo.ItemsSource = Titles` statement, the ComboBox remains blank. Why is this?

Comment: Drop the `DataContext="{Binding}"`

Comment: though `DataContext="{Binding}"` is redundant but should not be the cause of the problem as it will set the DataContext of combobox to windows DataContext, which is same... so problem is somewhere else.. can you share your complete noticewindow xaml

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Because, just as I said, it doesn't work without the assignment in the code-behind, and the binding in the XAML is there because it's supposed to work.

Comment: This will not solve your problem, but I would consider to rename the variable `tits`...

Comment: Any binding errors or anything else in the output window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you provided to us, your `ObservableCollection<TITLE> Titles { get; set; }` is defined as `private` (no access modifier being defined and `private` being the default one).

Given WPF databinding only works with public properties (see [MSDN related documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes)), it could explain why your binding isn't working properly and that you need to explicitly set your `ItemsSource` in code  behind to fill your `ComboBox`.

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation.

Answer (score 2):

So, your `ComboBox` is inside `NoticeWindow`, which has it's `DataContext` set to himself.
This is also where you defined the `Titles` property.

Like @AirL pointed out, `Titles` should be marked as `Public`:

```
public ObservableCollection<TITLE> Titles { get; set; }
```

Also, there is no need defining a `DataContext` on the `ComboBox` nor stating `TitleCombo.ItemsSource = Titles;`

Since the `ComboBox` inherits its `DataContext` from the `NoticeWindow`. You can just bind it to the `Titles` property

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TitleCombo"
        Width="100" 
        Height="20"
        DisplayMemberPath="TITLE_NAME"     
        SelectedValuePath="TITLE_CODEID"     
        ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}" />
```

Comment: Like @nit said if this doesn't work then your problem lies elsewhere. Post the entire xaml/code-behind to let us see why